# Editing activity_maps.xml?

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-layout, android-studio

I am using Google Maps and I'm trying to add a textview underneath the map fragment but can't.
It is my understanding that you can no longer edit the activity.xml but must instead edit content.xml? But there is no content_maps.xml?

I am new to Android Studio so apologies if this seems obvious.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i was understood that you want to show text on google-map view for this take relative layout as parent and put map fragment under relative layout width and height match parent below this map fragment place textview xml tag.